# prove using Nerode law that a language is regular

Tags: equivalence-relations, regular-language

prove that the language  = { ∈ Σ∗|∀1 ≤  ≤ : #() ≤  }, where  is defined over Σ = { | 1 ≤  ≤ } is regular using Nerode law.
basically the string w has, at most,  occurrences of the letter  at index  in Σ for each 1 ≤  ≤ .

The main problem I have is to defining the equivalent classes.

I'd like to ask for help in defining the equivalent classes, and showing that no string belongs to more than one equivalent class.
if there's an intuition for it, I'd love to hear that as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The Myhill-Nerode equivalence classes correspond to the states of the minimal automaton. Can you construct an automaton that recognizes this language?

Comment: hey @TomKern, thanks for replying.
while constructing an automaton that recognizes this language is not forbidden, the questions specifically wants the definitions of the equivalent classes.
so basically if that would help in defining the classes, I guess that could work, I just don't see how. could you expand on what you had in mind?

Comment: I am not sure to understand. Isn't $L$ a finite language?